# offce365マルチテナントアプリケーション

Tags: azure, iis

[Office 365 APIs MultiTenant Web Application](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant)

上記サンプルをベースに既存Webアプリケーションとマルチテナントのアプリケーションを開発・構築しようとしております。

上記サンプルで VS2013 の localhost では「sign in」から Office365 アカウント（xxxx.onmicrosoft.com）での認証は動作するのですが、これを IIS に構築した場合うまく動作しません。

現象としては、「sign in」で Office365 のログイン画面が表示され ID/PW を入力した後、https://login.windows.net/common/wsfederation の画面に遷移(POST)するのですが、画面が白いままの状態でローディングしています。(localhost では、正常に画面が表示され authorized になっています)

サンプルには以下の修正をしました。

- web.config に、`ida:ClientId` `ida:AppKey` を設定
- ContactsController.cs でエラーが出ましたので、`Microsoft.Office365.Discovery`、`Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices` まわりをコメントアウト

Azure AD のアプリーケーションでサイト URL は、適宜変更しています。

原因、トラブルシュートの方法などありましたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。